# Dwell time in wireless communication

Tags: wireless, wifi, telecommunications

In wireless communication `dwell time` is defined as the amount of time a device uses a particular channel. If we take the case of a `WiFi AP`, how is the `dwell time` calculated? I have the following questions also;

1. Doesn't the `AP` stay on one channel forever?
2. Why does the AP have to leave a channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dwell time (or time of occupancy) refers to the amount of time a Frequency Hop system (FHSS) **sub-channel** stays in that channel before hopping to another sub-channel. A logical FHSS channel has many sub-channels.
During this dwell time a data packet is transmitted. This repeats whenever a hop occurs to another sub-channel.
It is simply a general definition for time of occupancy applicable to FHSS systems mainly. It is not necessarily applicable to Wifi.

Answer (score 2):

The most reputable source is of course the official 802.11 standard. You'll have to pay for it however.

An old, simplified explanation is here:  [Presentation](https://grouper.ieee.org/groups/802/11/Documents/DocumentArchives/1996_docs/1196049D_scan.pdf)

We are talking *original* pre-802.11b WiFi here (1 and 2 Mb/s), the most recent version have more complex communication techniques.

In short, what you are choosing as 'channel' in WiFi is actually a 'channel group' (at the time there wasn't a dozen like these days, only 2 or 3); the real transmission channel is only 1MHz and for a number of reasons (EMC, band coexistance, environment frequency responce) the phy continuosly scan over a pseudo-fixed sequence of them (I don't know if WiFi has adaptive hopping, for example). Since the ISM is used by *everyone* there is a standard requirement to, say, avoid a microwave oven leakage.

That said that version of 802.11 is for all intent and purposes obsolete and it is more similar to Bluetooth (channel width and modulation match, too!) than to modern WiFi.